# HttpPostedFileBase always return null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, file-upload, upload

I don't know why my InvoicePDF is always null.

Model:

```
public class CreateEventViewModel
{
    // [FileExtensions(Extensions = "pdf", ErrorMessage = "Akceptuję tylko pliki PDF")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase InvoicePDF { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I've also added `maxRequestLength="65536"` in web.config and it didn't help.

```
<form id="f">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Event", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InvoicePDF, new { type = "file" })
            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoicePDF)*@
        </div>
        ...
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="CountPrice()">Oblicz cenę</button>
                    <input type="submit" value="Zapisz" class="btn btn-default" />
                    <button type="button" id="cancel" class="btn btn-default">Wyjdź</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</form>
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CreateEventViewModel ev)
{
  ...
}
```

I set breakpoint at the method start and `ev.InvoicePDF` is always null.
Where is the problem?

Comment: can you show your create action?

Comment: Sure, but for now I do nothing with file, just have breakpoint at the beginning and checking the posted model, so there is nothing what should help.
[Create action](https://pastebin.com/WCScM7Pn)

Comment: you can remove <form id="f">  since there is already a form

Comment: Maybe removing the outside form solves the problem, because everything looks.

Comment: Right, I've deleted form and it works, but quitting this form is quide longer (1-2 sec) than while `<form action="/Event/Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">` quits instantly. Don't know why, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your form tag.  Do a view source.  This will work:

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.CreateEventViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index53</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @*  remove this <form id="f">*@  
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InvoicePDF, new { type = "file" })
                    @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoicePDF)*@
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="CountPrice()">Oblicz cenę</button>
                        <input type="submit" value="Zapisz" class="btn btn-default" />
                        <button type="button" id="cancel" class="btn btn-default">Wyjdź</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        @*</form>*@
    </div>
</body>
</html>

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CreateEventViewModel ev)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index53()
    {
        CreateEventViewModel createEventViewModel = new CreateEventViewModel();
        return View(createEventViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: I've changed form to  `<form action="/Event/Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">` and working perfect.